# Exception Unable to locate Mix file: /employee/js/app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to launch a laravel-vuejs app in another app domain by creating a folder named `employee`. But the problem is it's displaying the following error :

`Exception Unable to locate Mix file: /js/app.js.`

But while I changed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

The app is now running, but the urls (generated in vue router) are returning `not found`

[image]

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2UJgNPXhBDSDHgAWO2mdVEgRlbpuhSOyXMBfuEiZPfY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/employee/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Check file name `js/app.js` is in file `public/mix-manifest.json` or not.

If not, run the command `npm run prod` or `npm run dev` to update the file mix-manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code at the end of laravel/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/{path?}', 'YourHomeController@index')->where('path', '.*')
```